# Karma test on BackboneJS

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, karma-runner, marionette

We used BackboneJS/Marionette for our application. It was previously a plain jQuery application. Currently, I'm able to display the HospitalName on my browser using regions so I'm good with that.

I'm still new with Marionette. She told us, our boss, to add testing. We decided to use Karma and PhantomJS. I started writing a spec file but I couldn't figure out how I can test if HospitalName is equal to "Ms Ranjit Ravi Heart Center" after DOM has finally been updated.

I'm assuming that my code is able to update DOM in PhantomJS using my spec file below.

Here is the data file: hospital.json

```
{ "HospitalName" : "Ms Ranjit Ravi Heart Center" }
```

This is the header/index.js

```
import Backbone from 'backbone';
import Module from 'marionette.component';
import Layout from './layout';
import Hospital from './hospital'; // pulls hospital.json

let PModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

export default Module.extend({

  viewClass: Layout,

  initialize: function () {
    this.model = new PModel(Hospital);
  }
});
```

and here is the template file using handlebars

```
<div>{{HospitalName}}</div>
```

Here is spec file that I've written so far

```
import Header from './header/index';
import {LayoutView} from 'backbone.marionette';

describe('Header Module', function () {
  before(function () {
    let header = new Header();

    $('<div id="regionHeader"></div>').appendTo('body');

    var HeaderView = LayoutView.extend({
      el: '#content',
      regions: {
        region: '.regionHeader'
      }
    });

    var headerLayout = new HeaderView();
    header.showIn(headerLayout.region);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your test has ```HeaderView``` which is based on the el ```#content``` but you are not adding this element to the DOM in your test, just ```regionHeader```. Try to wrap it with content, something like: ```$('<div id="content"><div id="regionHeader"></div></div>').appendTo('body');```

Comment: BTW I suggest you to use a Fixtures plugin for your test. Looks like you are using mocha, so you may consider using this to make it less manual: https://github.com/badunk/js-fixtures

Comment: Thanks a lot Tiago. I'll take a look at it now.